# How to interpret the StackExchange "unread messages" count?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, global-inbox

In recent months the StackExchange dropdown has been added to the top bar in Stack Overflow et al. Upon opening, the drop down has three buttons at the top: hot questions, all sites, and inbox. Periodically, the inbox button will include a count.

Assumption #1: the count on the inbox button is an "unread messages" count. **True?**

Assumption #2: the inbox displays questions, answers and favorites. **True?**

Scrolling through the list of messages in the inbox, I would expect to see some visual indication reflecting the "unread messages" count. That is, if the unread count is 2, I would expect to see 2 messages highlighted in some one (shading, arrow, etc.). But I find nothing of the sort. How does one know which 2 are being referenced?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to think about it is the number of entries in your StackExchange™ SuperCollider MultiDropdown™ inbox that have been added since you have last checked it.

The StackExchange™ SuperCollider MultiDropdown™ inbox is populated by events such as:

- one or more comment to a post of yours or in reply of a comment of yours.
- one or more answers to a question of yours.
- one or more chat mentions from a channel since you last opened the inbox which you haven't dismissed from the chat already.

Favourites do *not* show up in the SE™SCMD™, but only in the site's StackExchange™ ObsessiveCompulsive RedEnvelope™.

Comment: Needs more trademarks™.

Comment: @jball: Agreed!

Comment: Very useful answer and now I know the proper name :-).

Comment: Just one more thing: I notice that this is *not* documented in the common FAQ, so is it documented somewhere else?