# Which events count as "Unread inbox messages"?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to interpret the StackExchange “unread messages” count?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71675/how-to-interpret-the-stackexchange-unread-messages-count)

I've only recently registered on the site and am wondering which events count as an Inbox message?

Is there a definitive list anywhere I can look at?

Comment: Hi @steB! This question has already been asked here . One or more of the answers on that post can also answer *your* question here. [How to interpret the StackExchange "unread messages" count?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71675/how-to-interpret-the-stackexchange-unread-messages-count)

Comment: That's great, thanks @Lix. Shouldn't this have been an answer rather than a question (even if it was a re-direct, it answered my question)?

Comment: No worries - closed as a duplicate, the link is featured at the top for folks who search for this later.

Comment: @ste - I don't really like link only answers even if it *is* an internal link.